# How to know what people search?

Tags: seo, keywords

I have a web hosting and design company. I know that if I want a website, i search for web hosting. But not everyone is like that. How do I figure out what good keywords are? And more importantly, how do I do that without google insights, because the country I am targeting has low search volumes for most keywords?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best tool is probably the [Adwords Keywords Tools](https://adwords.google.com/o/Targeting/Explorer?__u=1000000000&__c=1000000000&ideaRequestType=KEYWORD_IDEAS). Type in "web hosting" and it will show you all the similar terms and popular they are.

Answer (score 2):

If the country you target has low search volumes you should consider traditional print media, such as posters and fliers.

Perhaps one way to figure out good keywords is to look at your competitors.

Answer (score 2):

Know your competitors and understand what keywords they are using. It will help you figure out what keywords to target.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you sign up to the 30 day free trial at [SEOmoz](http://www.seomoz.org/). Read their articles, use their tools - and if you find their service useful, subscribe.

Comment: I strongly disagree. Paying for anything for SEO is a waste of money. Not only is it not complex enough to require expensive tools, but everything you really need is free in some form somewhere. Not to mention people need to spend less time anayizing their sites and more time growing and improving them.

Comment: Couldn't agree more with John here, +1'd.

Comment: I am using that. It's awesome, just too expensive to use past my trial which is ending soon.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to know for sure is to ask people.

Ask your current clients, ask your colleagues, ask your competitors.

Also, if you feel your country has too small a sampling size for standard methods, then I would consider maybe thinking if there are any countries similar to your own but with larger populations? That might be a good start.